# "The" for mentioning the time after mentioning the place

Tags: definite-article

I have a following question:

I know I have to use first *place* then *time*. But I want to make sure about following sentence :

> That was a great experience to teach them at Yale University in (**the**) winter semester 2017.

Do I need to say "the" winter semester?

Comment: @R R  The question has already been asked and answered.You can it here

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao : Could you put its link here?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124622/whats-the-difference-between-in-winter-and-in-the-winter

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124622/whats-the-difference-between-in-winter-and-in-the-winter