# Spring is the best season of {a/the} year

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> Spring is the best season of ____ year.

*a* or *the*?

Year is not definite. It can be any year. Shouldn't it be "season of a year."?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between "in winter" and "in the winter"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/124622/9161)

Comment: Interesting, because worded a slightly different way, you wouldn't need the article at all. "Spring is the best time of year."  But if you're speaking about seasons, the prepositional phrase after "season" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is the best season of **the** year.

Just as you might say "Christmas is the best time of the year!"
You would not say "Christmas is the best time of **a** year!"

Comment: You used "the" because this year( 2024) is unique in the world(time and space)? within the context we are talking, is your statement equivalent to = spring is the best season of "this" year?

Comment: I did NOT use ""the" because this year( 2024) is unique in the world(time and space)".
I had NO particular year in mind!

Comment: "Two horns" is a feature of the cow. This way?

Comment: Trevor, your answer doesn't explain _why_ 'the' is correct. It's because we speak of _months/seasons of the year_ to mean 'a typical year' or 'every year' - similarly _days of the week_.

Comment: I agree with kate. But what I have understood is "every year".

Comment: I said "a typical year" because some years (at least, in the Northern hemisphere) may have a very cold or wet spring, but we still think of spring in general as being a happy and optimistic season.